# Success Toast VS Modal

Tags: modal-windows, toast

Success Toast or Modal? web desktop/tablet

User is on detailed page and clicks review > review takes user to a page with outliers > user completes actions on page > user clicks CTA Reviewed > User is taken back to detailed page.

I am not sure if I should have a simple success toast or a success modal... 
A success toast might be nice to put more emphasis on the action since in reality it is just a simple flag in the database that a manager looked at it and reviewed it.

Also secondary question is it ok practice to have a normal modal and a separate one for success?

Comment: I´m not sure if this threat is where I can add a question instead of open a new threat since my question is about this UI component and UX. Could a modal component interact with a toast after tap a "copy to clipboard" cta from a modal ? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Success Toast or Modal?

Modal window will require close action while the toast won't. In other words, the interaction cost will be lower for toasts. They will just show up inform the user and automatically fade away. While modals require 1 click/tap to close them. This is why I suggest using toasts.

> is it ok practice to have a normal modal and a separate one for
>   success?

Generally, modals should be avoided for feedback of operations. They are "Ok" when a review of the task is needed or some other manual validation.

Answer (score 4):

Building on what Kristiyan said in suggesting Toast's, I would suggest that you add in an activity feed, so the user can check back if they miss the toast being dismissed or the other option is to make the toast persist until the user closes it.

In that respect it's not completely in the users face like a modal dialogue, but the user receives the confirmation of their action.